# Is it a good idea to use GridSearch on small dataset and apply results on big one?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-mining, grid-search, hyperparameters

I have a Pipeline with TfidVectorizer and OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier). This is the parameters of the gridSearch I want to perform:

```
parameters = {'tfidf-vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 3)),
              'tfidf-vect__stop_words': (None,'english'),
              'tfidf-vect__min_df': (1e-3,1e-6),
              'tfidf-vect__max_features': (1e7,1e4),
              'tfidf-vect__norm': ('l1','l2',None),
              'tfidf-vect__use_idf': (True, False),
              'tfidf-vect__sublinear_tf': (True, False),
              'clf__estimator__alpha': (1e-5, 1e-7),
              'clf__estimator__loss':('hinge', 'log', 'modified_huber'),
              'clf__estimator__penalty':(None, 'l2', 'l1','elasticnet'),
              'clf__estimator__class_weight':("auto", None),
              'clf__estimator__warm_start':(True,False),
              'clf__estimator__average':(True,False,4,8,16)
}
```

**Problem:** I want to know which is the best combination of parameters but I can't run a gridSearch like this on 100k instances with my computer.

**Question:** How similar would the results of this kind of gridSearch be (maybe with smaller parameter set) on 100k instances dataset and a subset of lets say 10-20k samples?

As you may already know I am dealing with multi-label classification of texts problem.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a decent strategy. You aren't guaranteed in any way to get the best - but they should still be reasonably good. You do have to be careful though that you don't overfit to the smaller dataset with your parameter search.